# Find lines that match a pattern with parameterized subpattern, but keep only the first hit for each subpattern

Tags: python, regex, perl, awk, sed

The title is a bit long.

What I want is a way to get some lines from a file. These lines should be:

1. match the pattern. e.g. start without 'X' in the beginning and has string 'CH' in the line.
2. the first several characters after 'CH' pattern, can be sort into several categories. e.g. 1, 2 ,3.
3. I only need one line ( could be the first line) for each category.

the file is more like this: （more  close to what I need)

```
    X1 CH<1>
      N_CH<1> \
    X2 CH<2>
      N_CH<2>xx1 \
    X3 CH<2>
      N_CH<2>xx2 \
    X4 CH<3>
      N_CH<2>xx3 \
      N_CH<3>xx4 \
    X5 CH<4>
      N_CH<3>xx5
```

output:

```
N_CH<1> \
N_CH<2>xx1 \
N_CH<3>xx4 \
```

3 categories: 1, 2, 3

Note that xx2 and xx3 lines for CH2 and xx5 for CH3 line are neglected.

I tried with `sed`, but only managed to do one category at a time by:

```
sed -n '0,/CH2/ {/CH2/p}' file
```

And can not exclude the line start with 'X'.

Thanks in advance.

`Edit:`

There is no clear column or field for sort. Only thing I know is the number after 'CH' sort all the lines to different category and I need only one line from each category.

I sort of understand the 'sed' and 'sort' solution but the other more complex solutions may have advance features which I need to prepare myself further to understand all the detail mechanisms. But Thanks for all the answers!

so this line worked:

```
 sed -ne '/^[^X]/ {/N_CH/ p}' file | sort -t'>' -uk1,1
```

Comment: @avinashraj show the way to exclude lines start with 'X'. but the remaining thing is how to output all lines from the 3 categories? What if I have a large number of 'category' pattern after the main pattern 'CH'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
sed '/^X/d' file | sort -uk1,1
```

The lines beginning with an `X` can be deleted by the above sed command the resulting file can then be sorted by the first field (`-k1,1`) and all but the first of any duplicates removed (`-u`).

N.B. duplicates are removed based on the sorting key.

Comment: This one is very elegant and  can solve my problem with some modification for the deliminator of the column in the sort command. Fortunately, I have a special deliminator after the category number.

Answer (score 0):

I would tackle it like this:

- iterate your file, pattern matching the records you're looking for.
- insert matches into a hash - keyed on category.
- extract results from the hash

Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %categories;

#use 'magic' filehandle to read from either STDIN or 
#file specified on command line as arg. 
while (<>) {
    #skip lines where the first (non whitespace) character is an X. 
    next if m/^\s*X/;
    #capture two 'chunks' -the 'category id' and line - strips leading whitespace
    #only proceed if capture works. 
    if ( my ( $item, $category ) = m/(\w+CH(\d+).*)/ ) {
        #insert the captured "item" into the hash. 
        push( @{ $categories{$category} }, $item );
    }
}

#debugging
print Dumper \%categories;

foreach my $category ( sort keys %categories ) {
    #print first match in each category
    print $categories{$category}->[0], "\n";
    #could instead:
    #print join ( "\n", @{$categories{$category}}),"\n";
    #to print all
}
```

Prints debug of (comment out the Dumper line to remove):

```
$VAR1 = {
          '3' => [
                   'N_CH3 xx4 \\',
                   'N_CH3 xx5 \\'
                 ],
          '1' => [
                   'N_CH1 \\'
                 ],
          '2' => [
                   'N_CH2 xx1 \\',
                   'N_CH2 xx2 \\',
                   'N_CH2 xx3 \\'
                 ]
        };
```

And 'output':

```
N_CH1 \
N_CH2 xx1 \
N_CH3 xx4 \
```

Which I think is the desired result?

Note: I wasn't entirely clear on how/what 'category matches' you wanted, so it captures and groups them all.

You could instead:

```
while (<>) {
    next if m/^\s*X/;
    #test and assign regex matches
    if ( my ( $item, $category ) = m/(\w+CH(\d+).*)/ ) {
         #add "item" to category ONLY if it isn't already defined. 
         # //= is defined-equals assignment. 
         $categories{$category} //= $item;
    }
}
#print categories in order. 
foreach my $category ( sort keys %categories ) {
    print $categories{$category}, "\n";
}
```

Comment: my category is like:
the first number followed by the master pattern 'CH'. I don't care much about the follow stuff after that. 

I realized there is no easy way of doing this. Some other answers doesn't remove the lines that has stuff after CH1, CH2, CH3. I should update a test case that is much easier to present what I need.

Comment: Yes,  it is generally better to be specific about what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In python you can do it easily using `dictionaries`.

```
x=r"""X1 CH1
   N_CH1 \
X2 CH2
   N_CH2 xx1 \
X3 CH2
  N_CH2 xx2 \
X4 CH3
   N_CH2 xx3 \
  N_CH3 xx4 \
X5 CH4
   N_CH3 xx5 \""""
print dict((j,i) for i,j in re.findall(r"(^\s*([^X].*?CH\S+).*$)",x,flags=re.M|re.I)).values()
```

Output:`['  N_CH1 \\', '  N_CH3 xx5 \\"', '  N_CH2 xx3 \\']`

Answer (score 0):

I'd use something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Create an array to track seen categories
declare -A categories

agg() {
  if [[ "categories[$1]" != "" ]]; then
    categories[$1]="$@"
  fi  
}

Loop over the file to filter out the categories.
while read -r line; do
  echo "Elem: $line"
  agg $line
done < <(grep -v ^X test.so | sed 's/^\s\+//')

# Print out the array
for k in "${!categories[@]}"; do
  echo "$k -> ${categories[$k]}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using awk

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

/^[^X].*CH/ {
    split(substr($0, index($0, "CH")+2), a, " ");
    if (!(a[1] in lines)) {
        lines[a[1]]=$0
    }
}

END {
    for (k in lines){
        print lines[k]
    }
}
```

The idea is to store in an array the first line found for each category. We then output all the lines found at the end.

Output using your sample file :

```
$ awk -f so.awk file 
  N_CH1 \
  N_CH2 xx1 \
  N_CH3 xx4 \
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write it like you said it:

```
$ awk '$1!~/^X/ && /CH/ && !seen[$1]++' file
  N_CH1 \
  N_CH2 xx1 \
  N_CH3 xx4 \
```

Note that given the sample input you posted, you could get the same output with the much simpler:

```
$ awk '/^ / && !seen[$1]++' file
  N_CH1 \
  N_CH2 xx1 \
  N_CH3 xx4 \
```

so you might want to put a bit more thought into input that better represents your real data if you actually do need the first solution.

Comment: i guess this is similar to the sort method after match all the lines. But maybe awk has a way to specify deliminator to determine where $1 end? I am not familiar with awk. Seems quite powerful. !

Comment: sorry I don't know what you mean but awk is THE tool that the guys who invented shell created to be the general-purpose UNIX text-processing tool that shell scripts should call for that purpose so it's available on every UNIX system and yes, it is very powerful.